# How do I redirect and display a flash.message after using Response.outputStream in Grails?

Tags: grails

I need to redirect after using response.outputStream
I'm new to grails so I may not know if there is a simple way of doing it. Or if it is even possible.
Here is the snippet:

```
def filename = "ProgramA14_"+DASelected+"_backup.csv"
        def filecontent = response.outputStream
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename="+filename)
        response.contentType = "text/csv"
        filecontent << "program,da,area,date,forecastedReportedCumulative,forecastedReportedLow,forecastedReportedUpper,forecastedCorrectedCumulative,openPronto,openProntoLow,openProntoUpper,forecastedReportedWeekly,forecastedCorrectedWeekly\n"

        flash.message = "Sample Flash message."
        redirect(action:list, params:[programA14InstanceList: programA14DA, programA14InstanceTotal: programA14DA.count()])
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [One-Time Data plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/one-time-data)